# finite covering of a torus bundle over the circle is a torus bundle over the circle

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, covering-spaces, fiber-bundles, fibration

I am currently working through S.Wangs paper "[On the existence of maps of nonzero degree between aspherical 3-manifolds](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02571516)" and got stuck at a part where he claims that for a closed orientable and irreducible aspherical solvmanifold $M$ which is a torus bundle over the circle, any finite covering of $M$ is a torus bundle over the circle as well.

It is unclear to me why that should be the case, as I am not even sure that a finite covering of a fiber bundle always is a fiber bundle. Can you help me understand why this claim should be true?

Comment: Which page is it?

Comment: @ArcticChar It's in the first line of proposition 3 where it says that a finite covering of a plain 3-manifold is plain, "plain" being defined in the beginning of section 2. (p. 4 of the paper, p.150 in the journal)